# How to tell if a number is within a range in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need a way to start services on a server if the hostname value is between 500-549.

If it is not in that range then other services will be started.

I know how to do it all except identify if the number is a value between 500-549 so servernames containing values up to 499 and from 550-999 will have other services started.

So for example, the desired result would be:

```
server 500 start service A
server 530 start service b
server 660 start service A
```

Comment: Have you tried anything and gotten errors? Show us what you've done and we can probably help correct it.

Comment: Is the server name just numbers, or is it a combination such as name-number or similar? Also, is the name portion the same or different for each?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the server name is really just a number then:

```
$num = [int]$serverName
if ($num -ge 500 -and $num -le 549) {
    ... do one thing
}
else  {
    ... do another
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Use the `-In` operator and define a range with `..`

```
$a = 200
$a -In 100..300
```

As a bonus: This works too. Here, PowerShell silently converts a string to an integer

```
$a = "200"
$a -In 100..300
```

Output for both examples is

```
True
```

Comment: Note that the `100..300` part creates an array with 201 values (which will consume a lot of memory for larger ranges, and needs to be initialized), and the lookup in the array mrequires testing against all vaules (`-In` cannot tell that the array is sorted). Even when using a binary search (presuming a sorted array) it still requires more lookups then a simple `less than/grater than' check.          The code _may_ look more elegant, but it is not a coding style i would advise for this problem..

Comment: In addition to being worse for CPU and memory usage, **this is bad, bug-prone code.** A) Floating-point range bounds get cast to `[Int32]`, which involves rounding. Thus, `2 -In 0..1.5` and `-2 -In -1.5..0` both yield `$True`. B) The produced range is always integers, so a floating-point value will never be found.  `3.14 -In 1..5` yields `$False`. C) The maximum range size is limited. `0 -In 0..1GB` fails with `Array dimensions exceeded supported range`. D) Both ends of the range must fit in an `[Int32]`. `0 -In (2GB-1)..2GB` fails with `Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.`

Answer (score 24):

As a reply to [both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399104/how-to-tell-if-a-number-is-within-a-range-in-powershell/23399667#23399667) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399104/how-to-tell-if-a-number-is-within-a-range-in-powershell/32906978#32906978); code clarity and performance both matter, so I did some testing. As with all benchmarking, your results may differ; I just did this as a quick test..

**Solution 1**

```
(($value -ge $lower) -and ($value -le $upper))
```

**Solution 2**

```
$value -In $lower .. $upper
```

**Test**

```
$value = 200
$lower = 1

for ($upper = $lower; $upper -le 10000000; $upper += $upper) {
    $a = Measure-Command { (($value -ge $lower) -and ($value -le $upper)) } | Select -ExpandProperty Ticks
    $b = Measure-Command { ($value -in $lower .. $upper) } | Select -ExpandProperty Ticks
    "$value; $lower; $upper; $a; $b"
}
```

Results:

[image]

When plotted (in Excel), I got the following graph:

[image]

**Conclusion**

For small ranges, there is no big difference between solutions.
However, since the performance penalty for larger ranges does occur (measurable starting at 256 elements), and you may not have influence on the size of the range, and ranges may vary per environment, I would recommend using `solution 1`. **This also counts (especially) when you don't control the size of the range.**

Answer (score 0):

If you do this a lot, here is a function to cut down on typing and mistakes:

```
function Test-Range
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Takes three integers: Value being tested, Low end of range, High end of range
        If the Value is the same as Low or High it returns True
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 0
        )]
        [Int] $Value,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 1
        )]
        [Int] $Low,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 2
        )]
        [Int] $High
    )
    return (($Value -ge $Low) -and ($Value -le $High ))
}
```

To execute the function do one of the following:

```
if (Test-Range 1 2 3) # This will return false
if (Test-Range -Value 1 -Low 2 -High 3) # This will return false
```

Or if you prefer a slightly more readable version but a few more keys

```
function Test-Range
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Takes three integers: Value being tested, Low end of range, High end of range
        If the Value is the same as Low or High it returns True
    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 0
        )]
        [Int] $Value,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 1
        )]
        [array] $Range
    )
    return (($Value -ge $Range[0]) -and ($Value -le $Range[1] ))
}
```

This would be called like so:

```
if (Test-Range 1 (2, 3)) # This will return false
if (Test-Range -Value 1 -Range (1, 3)) # This will return True
```

Comment: I suppose you could switch things around so that the value is in the middle... whichever makes more sense to you.