# powershell how to pass multiple number into number range in if condition

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I have below code, **I am passing 101,102 number in $a**:

```
$a = Read-host enter number 
$a -In 100..300
```

It's gives me 'False' instead 'True' ,I want use this concept in my script but unable to get true result
Reference link: [How to tell if a number is within a range in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399104/how-to-tell-if-a-number-is-within-a-range-in-powershell#)

Comment: Do you actually enter "101,102" (not 101 once, then 102)?

Comment: @zett42 I want use 101,102 like that!!

Comment: And the expected result is `$true` only if all numbers are in given range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's good information in the existing answers, but let me attempt a systematic explanation:

- [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) only ever returns a *single object*, of type *string* (`[string]`).
- If you want to interpret that string *as a list of items*, you'll have to do your own *splitting*, such as with `-split`, the [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split).
- Additionally, if you want the string (tokens) to be *numbers*, you'll have to *cast* to the desired numeric type, e.g. `[int]`
- Finally, the [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) can only test a *single* LHS object against the RHS array. To test *multiple* ones you need to test *each*, which the sample code below does with the [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where):

```
# Prompt the user for a comma-separated list of numbers, split the result
# string into individual number strings and convert them to integers.
# Note: This will fail with non-numeric tokens.
#       Entering nothing will yield a single-element array containing 0
#       Add error handling as needed.
$numbers = [int[]] ((Read-Host 'Enter list of numbers') -split ',')

# Make sure all numbers provided are in the expected range.
if ($outOfRangeNumbers = $numbers.Where({ $_ -notin 100..300 })) {
  Write-Warning "Numbers that are out of range: $outOfRangeNumbers"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning to pass multiple numbers separated by a comma, first you'll need to convert the `string` into an `array` and, in addition, you will need to loop through those values and compare each of them with the `-in` operator.

Here is an example of how to achieve that:

```
[regex]::Matches(
    (Read-host "Enter numbers separated by a comma"), '\d+'
).Value.ForEach({$_ -in 100..300})
```

Example:

```
Enter numbers separated by a comma: 123,5000,10,200
True
False
False
True
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are entering `101,102` verbatim when prompted, then it's being interpreted as a string, not an integer and cannot be cast as anything else automatically. The string `101,102` is not an integer in the range of `100` to `300`.

If you enter `101` *or* `102` when prompted, `True` will be returned.

Comment: If I want to go with 101,102 then any possibilities!!

Comment: @Nilam do you want the input to be interpreted as the number 101102, or do you want to enter multiple numbers at a single prompt and have each tested individually? Your requirements (and sample input) aren't clear.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help.